# using wget to download multiple pages of a website

Tags: html, wget

I'm trying to download website using `wget` that has multiple pages. Please consider, https://example.com as an example website for this question and it has multiple pages like:

https://example.com/1
https://example.com/2
....
https://example.com/100
( I do know it does not have any pages like these but for better understanding taking this site as example.)

how can I download all pages from 1 to 100

I tried using:

```
wget --mirror https://google.com/{1..100}
```

but this didn't work and got the following error:
`HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found 2023-02-22 14:09:51 ERROR 404: Not Found.`

Also please suggest to use some additional arguments like `-k` `-p` `--convert-links` etc.

Comment: There's no https://google.com/{1..100}

Comment: I took google.com as an example, i do know that it doesnt have 1 to 100 pages.

Comment: Do you want the first 1OO results of the numbers 1 to 100 as an id? Please, clarify. For explicit example, use example.org

Comment: Please dont get confused much, I just want to "download/save on my desktop" all the webpages i.e. from example.org/1 to example.org/100.

Comment: Does my answer solves you issue?

Comment: It worked, but download all the contents of the first page i.e, http://example.org/1, instead i wanted it to download till http://example.org/100

Answer (score -1):

One way:

```
lynx -dump -listonly --nonumbers -hiddenlinks=merge --dump http://example.org |
    head -n100 |
    xargs wget
```

you even can filter links with [grep](/questions/tagged/grep):

```
lynx -dump -listonly --nonumbers -hiddenlinks=merge --dump http://example.org |
    grep -F 'index.php?id=' |
    head -n100 |
    xargs wget
```